# Using conjunctions trouble

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, phrase-meaning, conjunctions, conversation

Which paragraph sounds sort of a native one and is grammatically right ???

Note : I put the Sentences needed to be checked between brackets.

1-It is true that we can't go out and we can't travel like before, (but think about it the other way around). We get to spend more time with our families and do a lot of things together.

2-It is true that we can't go out and we can't travel like before,( but on the other hand), We get to spend more time with our families and do a lot of things together.

3-It is true that we can't go out and we can't travel like before, (but, on the contary), We get to spend more time with our families and do a lot of things together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is grammatical, though a bit wordy.

The second option is most natural, though the "we" after the bracketed part shouldn't be capitalized, because it continues the first sentence.

The third option seems least natural to me, because what follows isn't exactly contrary to what came before, though it is looked at differently. That difference is better expressed by "on the other hand."

Comment: Thank a lot, That's exactly my opinion. But I want to ask you again about the sentence ( Think about it the other way around ) . Is it ok to be used ??

Comment: Yes, it's alright. You could also say "...but think  of the advantages/good side/the upside".